# Change default Chrome built-in dictionary

Tags: chrome-for-android, dictionary

I have Samsung Galaxy S7 on Android 8.0 Oreo. I have recently noticed that once I select a word in Chrome, I get an option "Dictionary" that would take me to this app. This is the icon of the app:

[image]

I can't uninstall this app, thus this means that this is an app by default/built-in.

I want to change the dictionary. By this, I mean when you select one word in a webpage, there is this popup that comes up with the last option dictionary. The built-in dictionary is quite poor for certain languages, and I'm using dictionaries quite a lot.

Ideally, I'd like to use [GoldenDict](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.goldendict.android), but any other dictionary would be fine.

Is there any way of using another dictionary from the contextual menu of a web page in Chrome?

Comment: I don't have this Dictionary option in Chrome, and I checked a couple of other Android devices too, and none offer it, so most probably it's an option offered by your OS manufacturer. You should probably specify your phone model and Android version in the question.

Comment: [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vaibhav.dictionary) can integrate into Chrome as well and offers reasonably adequate set of words.

Answer (score 0):

I also do not like this built in dictionary. I don't think you can get rid of it, but you can add a better dictionary with pop up functionality, like OnTouch (cheap but good) or Oxford English Dictionary (more expensive)

Answer (score 0):

Download this.. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=livio.pack.lang.en_US&hl=en_IN
And in default apps section check if there's any option of default dictionary(there usually isn't)
In chrome check if there's another option of dictionary..

Comment if you're have any doubt